# passing variables into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS c++

Tags: c++, variables, libcurl

I am trying to pass a variable into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. My current code:

```cpp
size_t curl_write( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  std::string cmd(static_cast<char*>(ptr), size * nmemb);
  redi::ipstream proc(cmd.c_str(), redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstderr);

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(proc.out(), line))
    std::cout << line << '\n';

  CURLcode sendb;
  CURL *bnd;

  bnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)line.size());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, line.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
  

  sendb = curl_easy_perform(bnd);

  std::cout << sendb;

  curl_easy_cleanup(bnd);
  bnd = NULL;

  if (proc.eof() && proc.fail())
    proc.clear();
}
```

This sends some weird hex thing `V\x1b{` in the POST request.

I've tried adding `line.c_str()` but that does not work. It works when hard-coding the data.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the value of `line`?

Comment: @김선달 Line has the output of cmd

Comment: I mean its value

Comment: @김선달 its sporatic and up to the user but i am testing it with the output of the command dir

Comment: @JonathanColetti What kind of request are you using `curl_write()` with? Why are you forwarding arbitrary bytes to another URL? And why are you setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` to 4 instead of `line.size()`?

Comment: BTW, you do realize that `std::getline()` clears the passed `std::string` before reading into it, so when the `getline()` loop reaches the end of the `proc` stream and stops iterating, `line` will be left empty when you pass it to curl.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string line` can't be passed to a C API function. Use `line.c_str()` like you did for `agent_name`.

```
curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, line.c_str());
```

Also it is better to pass the string length rather than a magic constant 4 or not to set the length of 0-terminated string.

```
// Unnecessary for 0-terminated string.
curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, line.c_str());
```

Comment: You are correct about needing to use `c_str()`, but there is no need to use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` in this case since `curl_easy_perform()` is a blocking call, so the `std::string` will not be freed until the request is finished. Using local variables is fine.

Comment: I mentioned that adding c_str() didnt fix it in my post. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, just missed it looking at the function to be like doing init.

Comment: @JonathanColetti This can not be not working. Show your actual code with c_str().

Comment: @S.M. I could make a edit with the full code as it is only 100 lines and might give some better insight